# Unity C#: How to make moving character like in Feeding Frenzy?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, click, unityscript

This game I create that the characters is moving to right only by following the cursor. I want like Feeding Frenzy, when I moving the mouse the characters will follow the cursors and when it press short left click the character have more speed.

The problem in my code is when I press long left click, the character also going faster.

this is my code:

```
//variable for moving characters
public float moveSpeed;
public float turnSpeed;
private Vector3 moveDirection;

//variable for detect short/long click
private float t0;
private bool longClick;
private bool shortClick;

void Start () 
{
    moveDirection = Vector3.right;
    t0 = 0f;
    longClick = false;
    shortClick = false;

}

void Update () 
{
    // code to moving my characters (moving to right only) 
    Vector3 currentPosition = transform.position;
    Vector3 moveToward = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint( Input.mousePosition );
    moveDirection = moveToward - currentPosition;
    moveDirection.z = 0; 
    moveDirection.Normalize();
    if (moveDirection.x <= 0)
    {
        moveDirection = Vector3.right;
    }       

    Quaternion rot = Quaternion.LookRotation (transform.position - moveToward, Vector3.forward);
    rot *= Quaternion.Euler (0, 0, 90); 
    transform.rotation = rot;
    transform.eulerAngles = new Vector3 (0, 0, transform.eulerAngles.z);
    Vector3 target = moveDirection * moveSpeed + currentPosition;
    transform.position = Vector3.Lerp( currentPosition, target, Time.deltaTime );
    float targetAngle = Mathf.Atan2(moveDirection.y, moveDirection.x) * Mathf.Rad2Deg;
    transform.rotation = Quaternion.Slerp( transform.rotation, 
                         Quaternion.Euler( 0, 0, targetAngle ), 
                         turnSpeed * Time.deltaTime );


    //THIS IS MY PROBLEM! 
    //IN MY CODE BELOW, WHEN I PRESS LONG CLICK IT HAVE moveSpeed=12.
    //I WANT moveSpeed = 12 WHEN I PRESS SHORT CLICK ONLY
    if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown (0)) 
    {
        t0 = Time.time;
        moveSpeed = 12;
    }

    else if (Input.GetMouseButtonUp(0) && (Time.time - t0) > 0.5f)
    {
        longClick = true;
        moveSpeed = 3;
    }
    else if (Input.GetMouseButtonUp(0) && (Time.time - t0) < 0.5f)
    {
        shortClick = true;
        moveSpeed = 3;
    }
    longClick = false;
    shortClick = false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    function Update()
{
    longClick = false;     //Remove this
    shortClick = false;    //Remove this
    if ( Input.GetMouseButtonDown (0) )
    {
           t0 = Time.time ;
           longClick = false;
            shortClick = false;
    }

    if ( Input.GetMouseButtonUp(0)  (Time.time -  t0) < 0.2 )
   {
        longClick = false;
        shortClick = true;
   }

    if ( Input.GetMouseButtonUp(0)  (Time.time -  t0) > 0.2 )
   {
      longClick = true;
      shortClick = false;
   }

       //Process Movement
}
```

And then use `if(longclick)` or `if(shortClick)` to do your speed. When there is a short click, the character moves fast and in the next update, the character goes back to the same speed.  If you want the character to continue moving in same speed till it gets the next click, then remove the lines right after update.

process the character movement after the `longClick` and `shortClick` is set.